# Subtracts two columns of different lengths, based on criteria (date) in another column(s)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I couldn't find an answer on this here or googling but maybe I'm using the wrong words.

I essentially have 4 columns

[image]

Two lists of different sizes with different dates. I'd like to subtract the cells based on similar dates. As such, with this example set, I would get the following, (B minus A)

[image]

I've tried using =IF ; =SUMIF; and =MATCH; but I just don't seem to be doing it correctly. Thank you for any help.

Edit - C Column should be [-1, 0 , 1]! Did this by hand, hence the need for this help haha

Comment: Does your version of Excel support FILTER?

Comment: and why is `5-Jan` equal to `-8` and not `0`?

Comment: Yes I can use FILTER and , Scott - haha yes.... it's 0. Did it by hand, clearly I have no idea how to do this except by hand :/

Answer (score 2):

If you have Office 365 you could use something like:

`=MAP(F2:F4,LAMBDA(c,LET(a,TOCOL(A2:C7/(B2:D7=c),2),DROP(a,1)-TAKE(a,1))))`

If you have an older Excel you could try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REPT($C$2:$C$7,$D$2:$D$7=F2)/1,0))-SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REPT($A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5=F2)/1,0))
```

It might require being entered with `Ctrl+shift+enter`

[image]

Or a more classic approach: `=INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(F2,$D$2:$D$7,0))-INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(F2,$B$2:$B$5,0))`

Answer (score 1):

### Subtract Common SumIfs

[image]

```
=LET(fl,B2:B11,fv,A2:A11,sl,D2:D16,sv,C2:C16,
    SF,LAMBDA(v,l,i,SUM(FILTER(v,l=i))),
    ci,IFNA(INDEX(sl,XMATCH(UNIQUE(fl),sl)),""),
    cl,SORT(FILTER(ci,ci<>"")),
    cv,IFERROR(BYROW(cl,LAMBDA(r,SF(sv,sl,r)-SF(fv,fl,r))),""),
HSTACK(cv,cl))
```

**The Variables**

```
fl - first lookup
fv - first values
sl - second lookup
sv - second values
SF - SumFilter: a LAMBDA function to sum up filtered data
ci - common lookup indexes ordered by the first lookup
cl - common lookup sorted ascending
cv - common values (subtracted second sums from first)
```